# How to add custom validation to template-driven form without creating new directive (max-characters)

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a template-driven form. I need to add custom validator, which will detect max characters in input and show an error message and if we receive an error message, button 'ok' must be disabled. I have 5-7 inputs and in the code example, I provide just 2 to show syntax.

I tried max-characters = 10 but that attribute disallows typing more than 10. In my case, user can type whatever he wants characters (more than 10) but after he types 10th, it should be error message and button must be disabled.

Unfortunately, I'm new in template-driven forms and my task is to do it only in template-forms. Guys, please could someone explain to me the best way to make my form with inputs and custom validator works? Any help will helpful.

```
<form
    class="my_ex_form"
    #myExForm="ngForm"
    novalidate>
    <div class="input">
      <label class="required">One</label>
      <input
        ngxTrim='keyup'
        required
        #one="ngModel"
        name="one"
        maxlength="64"
        [(ngModel)]="ex.name"
        placeholder="Enter...">
      <span *ngIf="one.value?.length >= 10" class="error-text">Max length 10 characters.</span>
    </div>
   <div class="input">
      <label class="required">Two</label>
      <input
        ngxTrim='keyup'
        required
        #two="ngModel"
        name="two"
        maxlength="10"
        [(ngModel)]="ex.nameTest"
        placeholder="Enter...">
      <span *ngIf="two.value?.length >= 10" class="error-text">Max length 10 characters.</span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <button
        type="submit"
        [disabled]="someOtherInputsValue || someOtherCheckboxesValue"
        class="btn btn-short"
        (click)="validate(myExForm)">
        ok
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a reference variable and use manually setError, see that in the example, my reference variable is "input1", and I make equal to a "ngModel", this allow us use  input1.invalid, or input1.control.setErrors() some like

```
<input #input1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="value" 
   (input)="input1.control.setErrors(input1.value.length>10?'max length':null)">
{{input1.invalid}}
```

If we want we can make a function

```
checkControl(control:NgModel)
  {
    if (control.control.value && control.control.value.length>10)
      control.control.setErrors({error:"Max length exceded"})
    else
    control.control.setErrors(null)
  }
```

And our form is like

```
<form #myform="ngForm">
<input #input1="ngModel" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="value1" 
   (input)="checkControl(input1)">
{{input1.invalid}}
<input #input2="ngModel" name="input2" [(ngModel)]="value2" 
   (input)="checkControl(input2)">
{{input2.invalid}}
</form>
{{myform.invalid}}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjqv8y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried such solution but get an error `Argument type "max length" is not assignable to parameter type  ValidationErrors | null`

Comment: I updated my answer creating a function and a stackblitz. In Angular 8 I get not error asigning  literal, not an object

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom directive if there's no dependencies between the values of your controls. I tried running your code and it works as expected except for the `OK` button.

You could use `myExForm.invalid` to set/unset `disabled` attribute in the button element.

Comment: I need to know how many characters in input, and even if my input have an error message (because of more than 10 characters) form must be invalid. I just really don't know how to add such validation to template form... I tried many solutions, but they all were based on adding a new directive. Maybe you have some things how to make button disabled when inputs have more than 10 characters? I can write something like `[disabled]='one.value.length>10 && two.value.length>10' but it's not the good solution, because I need to check all inputs on their values (it could be from 5 to 7)

Comment: you could use the reference variables `one` and `two`(which are the `FormControl`s) to do things like check if your control has errors using `one.errors.required` or one.hasError('required'). Please refer to [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) for more information. Is your `OK` button's disability is based on only these two fields (one & two)?? If no then, maybe you could use `[attr.disabled] = myExForm.invalid ? 'disabled' : ' '`

Comment: I guess that I provide a bad explanation. I need to check error for characters but I can't because I don't know how. I'm tyring something like this right now: `this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {console.log('f', form)}` and from that function I can see values and maybe do something with them. Thanks for your time and answer :)

Comment: Try printing `{{ ex.name }}` in your HTML. it should show you the updated values and you could use ngModelChange event emitter to react to the changes which I doubt will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

what I made:

```
 <form
    class="my_ex_form"
    #myExForm="ngForm"
    novalidate>
    <div class="input">
      <label class="required">One</label>
      <input
        ngxTrim='keyup'
        required
        #one="ngModel"
        name="one"
        [(ngModel)]="ex.name"
        placeholder="Enter...">
      <span *ngIf="errMsg" class="error-text">Max length 10 characters.</span>
    </div>
   <div class="input">
      <label class="required">Two</label>
      <input
        ngxTrim='keyup'
        required
        #two="ngModel"
        name="two"
        [(ngModel)]="ex.nameTest"
        placeholder="Enter...">
      <span *ngIf="errSecMsg" class="error-text">Max length 10 characters.</span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <button
        type="submit"
        [disabled]="invalidValue()"
        class="btn btn-short"
        (click)="validate(myExForm)">
        ok
      </button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and my component is:

```
   errMsg = false;
   errSecMsg = false;
   formChangesSubscription: any;

   ngOnInit() {
        this.checkChanges();
      }
checkChanges() {
    this.formChangesSubscription = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(form => {
      this.errMsg = form.name && form.name.length > 10;
      this.errSecMsg = form.nameTest && form.nameTest.length > 10;
    });
  }
```